# Use React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML to pass onClick event (that uses this.props) to an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, redux

I'm working on an internationalized site that uses json files to dynamically fill in copy on the page.

I'm working with a paragraph tag that has a hyperlink that it receives from the json file by way of React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

The problem is that, for legal reasons, I can't simply embed a link like this. I need to trigger a popup warning any time a user clicks a link that takes them away from the site (it's a site for children).

Here is how I handle this logic on another page, where a click triggers the showPopUp helper function.

```
<a onClick={ ()=> { this.props.actions.showPopUp(retailer.url) }}>
    <p>Click me</p>
</a>
```

I tried just cutting and pasting this code into the json file, but it doesn't work. It seems like I need something like a dangerouslySetJSX attribute, but I don't think that exists.

Am I missing something? Or does anyone have a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why it works on the other page but not this one? Seems like there might be an issue in your page setup.

Comment: IThe problem is that I want to add the click event to a a specific word in the JSON string that is being piped into the DOM. Currently, that is possible because of the dangerouslySetInnerHTML... I just through an anchor tag around the work in the json file and it renders on the page.

Comment: But what I want is to add an onClick event to the string coming from the JSON file that references a method that is defined in my Redux actions, and only accesible via the React component's props.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah not sure if that is possible. Try to bind it to the onClick event with just vanilla JS rather than trying to make JSX work.  Something like `onClick="this.props.actions.showPopup(retailer.url)"`. I highly doubt that will work though since this.props isn't resolved yet.  You basically need to find out what React transpiles `onClick={ ()=> { this.props.actions.showPopUp(retailer.url) }}` to and add that as a plain string.

Comment: Hmmm... yeah, that makes sense. Any idea how to do that? Can I access it in the Dev Tools somehow?

Comment: Hmmm, I took a look in the elements tab and using the React dev tools plugin and I'm not seeing what you are looking for. Maybe View Page Source??

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In the end, I just wrapped the entire paragraph in an anchor tag, removed the underline text-decoration from the <p> tag and added a span to the words I wanted to link to and added a cursor:pointer and underline styling to the class.